# Removing parts from a Facelet template on certain pages

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a facelet template that has a menu along with other things not included in the code below:

```
<h:head>
   ..............................
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:include src="/menu.xhtml" />
   ..............................       
   ..............................
<h:body>
```

This template is used by all of my pages around 30:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    template="/layout/template.xhtml">

</ui:composition>
```

There are very few pages that need to use everything in the template except the menu. Is there a way to specify from those pages not to show the menu.

I am looking for a way in facelets, like passing a facelet param or something. I have thought of the following options but I am trying to avoid them:

1. Create another template exactly like the existing one but without the menu and use it in those pages
2. Take the menu out of the template and use on the needed pages but that would mean adding the menu to around 25 pages, I would like to keep the menu in the template.

Comment: Why exactly is this question tagged both JSF 1.2 and JSF 2.0? It's only confusing. If you're using JSF 2.0, don't tag JSF 1.2. If you're using JSF 1.2, don't tag JSF 2.0. If you've tried *both* and the same problem manifests in *both* versions, then remove both tags and stick to `[jsf]` tag.

Comment: I remove JSF 1.2, and JSF 2.0 tags

Answer (score 0):

One for me working solution for this is a bean that deliveres a boolean for a list of files and in the template you are using this for toggling the include:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{toogleMenu.withMenu}" >
       <ui:include src="/menu.xhtml" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       ...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

The bean is something like this, perhaps you can use .properties or DB instead of the enum with the files that has no menu.

```
@Named(value = "toogleMenu")
@ViewScoped
public class ToogleMenuBean implements Serializable {
   ...
   private static final String[] EXCLUDE_FILES = { "nomenu.xhtml", ... };

   public String getCurrentURL() {
     FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
     return req.getRequestURL().toString();
  }              

   public String getCurrentFile() {
     String url = getCurrentURL();
     return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
   }

  public List<String>getExcludes() {
    List<String> excludes = new LinkedList<>();
    excludes.addAll(Arrays.asList(ToogleMenuBean.EXCLUDE_FILES));
    return excludes;
  }

  public boolean isWithMenu() {
    boolean ret = ! getExcludes().contains(getCurrentFile());
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the idea on getCurrentUrl here: 
[How do I get request url in jsf managed bean without the requested servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196501/how-do-i-get-request-url-in-jsf-managed-bean-without-the-requested-servlet)

I use this idea for toggling extra debug infos etc. for a fixed list of files.