# how jsf get server url

Tags: jsf, url, path, externalcontext

all

My web project run in tomcat.Its path is`http://localhost:8080/test/index.html`.

How to get the url = "http:/localhost:8080/test/" throught ExternalContext?

thanks advanced.

Comment: Duplicate question/answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196501/how-do-i-get-request-url-in-jsf-managed-bean-without-the-requested-servlet

Answer (score -1):

You can access to the context path using [`ExternalContext#getRequestContextPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestContextPath()). From its javadoc:

> Return the portion of the request URI that identifies the web application context for this request.
>
> *Servlet*: This must be the value returned by the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest method getContextPath()`.

Usage in code:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath()
```