# display user profile in facelet based on remote_user/session attribute

Tags: java, jsf, session, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to display User Profile data stored in Oracle on a facelet page.  But I don't know how to specify the user id from the Session in my managed bean ("myUserId" in the @PostConstruct below).

### facelet

```
receiving email? #{member.receive_email} <br/>
signed waiver? #{member.signed_waiver} <br/>
```

### Managed Bean/Backing Bean (not sure the correct terminology)

```
@SessionScoped
public class MemberProfile implements Serializable {

@Inject
private EntityManager em;
private Member member;

@Produces
@Named
public Member getMember() {
  return member;
}

@PostConstruct
public void getMemberData() {
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Member> criteria = cb.createQuery(Member.class);
  Root<Member> _member = criteria.from(Member.class);

  criteria.select(_member);
  criteria.where(cb.equal(_member.get("userid"), "myUserId"));
  member = em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
}
```

When I hardcode the user ID it works but I want to query the user logged in. Well, no one really logs in to the web app just their PC.  At my company, IT has set up Apache to use Kerberose and Active Directory and sends that to JBoss. So I have a user id through `request.getAttribute("REMOTE_USER")`

I have a servlet filter which reads the request.getAttribute("REMOTE_USER") and sets an object `User` which has basic employee data (phone, email, name, etc..) in a httpsession.  The member profile is now from another Oracle table for an employee ski club application.

In the facelet I can access the user data like this:

```
Hello: ${STKUserSession.fname }&nbsp;${STKUserSession.lname }&nbsp;(${STKUserSession.userId})
```

So how do I utilize this STKUserSession.userId in the query builder above. Maybe I can't figure it out because I am using the wrong approach altogether

### Edit

Based on the answer below, the suggestion is to do this, but I'm not so sure this is the cleanest approach.

```
     HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
     HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
     STKUser authenticatedUser = (STKUser) session.getAttribute("STKUserSession");
     String autheticatedBadge = authenticatedUser.getBadge();
     criteria.where(cb.equal(_member.get("badge"), autheticatedBadge));
```

Comment: So, if i understand you correctly, you have a `User` class (or `STKUser`?) that you construct from the `REMOTE_USER` attribute? And you named it `STKUserSession` in the view? If it's `@SessionScoped` as well, you can `@Inject` it into your member profile and just use it as a regular object.

Comment: @mabi Yes in a Servlet filter I get the windows login id using request.getAttribute("REMOTE_USER"). I then build the user "STKUser" by querying our employee phonebook and put this object into the http session. Your suggrestion sounds very elegant. I will investigate how to implement injecting this object into member profile.

Comment: @mabi I just reread your comment.  STKUser is not SessionScoped.  It is an object used in other places than just filter authentication, so not sure if it is a good idea to annotate with SessionScope.  I wonder if I should refactor out a new class??

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the username of the one making the request with

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
```

or

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();
```

> So how do I utilize this STKUserSession.userId in the query builder
>   above. Maybe I can't figure it out because I am using the wrong
>   approach altogether

Just pass the username retrieved from one of the above method as a parameter into your sql query, something like the following should work :

```
criteria.where(cb.equal(_member.get("userId", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal().getName())));
```

Comment: From what BalusC has stated in this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196501/how-do-i-get-request-url-in-jsf-managed-bean-without-the-requested-servlet isn't this approach a code smell?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you explain why it is code smell? Otherwise, you need a session scoped bean to store such profile information (and if you need it lot of times). The wrong approach is to have too many calls to the `FacesContext` object, one is ok, but you won't even need it if you had a `@SessionScoped` bean which you could inject without problem.

Comment: I think you summed up the smell in your comment. See BalasC comment in other thread. I am looking into using `@SessionScoped` and injecting bean but unfortunately refactoring my common legacy code isn't going to be trivial, but I think in the long run it will be better

Comment: Then simply add/create a new session scoped bean, in the long run, it will be useful to have one.

Comment: Is your problem solved now, and the question answered ?

Comment: not quite. In the ideal case, what mabi suggested in his answer (and you the same in one of your comments) is probably the correct solution. But for me, since I'm using shared library which had my authentication, which was using a servlet filter to set the session after querying HR data using the remote user, it is not as simple. It might warrant a new question.  Both your answers are good and I can accept based on best practices, but I need more assistance, which again Ill prob open another Quest. Should I mark one ans here as accepted even though I need more help?

Comment: I'm not sure about the procedure as I'm quite new here, but I think you should open a new question, describe your login mechanism and re-explain the problem you are facing. It's up to you to accept it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do:

1) create a holder object for `STKUser` object:

```
@Named("STKUserSession")
@SessionScoped
public class STKUserSession implements Serializable {
    private STKUser instance;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        instance = new STKUser(Faces.getRequestAttribute("REMOTE_USER"));
    }
    // facade methods for STKUser
}
```

2) Use the `STKUserSession` object to get your profile:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MemberProfile implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private STKUserSession user;

    @PersistenceContext
    private transient EntityManager em;

    private Member member;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Member> cq = cb.createQuery(Member.class);
        Root<Member> root = cq.from(Member.class);

        cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("badge"), user.getBadge()));
        member = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Note that this is demo code: you probably want error checking for missing badges, catching the exceptions thrown from `getSingleResult()` (or use `getResultList()`). It also uses the [omnifaces](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#getRequestAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) shortcut method(s).

Also, check for cycles: your CDI implementation will complain if you inject `MemberProfile` into a bean used by `STKUserSession`.

Comment: OK, starting to understand.  You were not talking about annotating my STKUser class, then.  I think that would cause a rippling affect because I use STKUser as a DTO for say when querying a list of employees, a List of STKUsers is created.